# CosmosDb querying 2 object types in same collection and same partition

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have two document types in the same collection: `Order`, `Shipping`.

The relation is: one shipping have one or many orders.

The `order` has a `shipping_id`.

I would select orders listing some properties of shipping.

RDBMS talking it is a classic JOIN but I can't find a solution with DocumentDb.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

CosmosDb is not a RDBMS. For that reason you will have to perform two queries. First, retrieve the shipping(s) that you're interested in and then issue another query retrieving the order(s) based on the shipping_id. If you know the shipping_id ahead of time, you can even issue these queries in parallel using something like `Task.WhenAll`. Another option is wrap this logic inside of a Stored Procedure. This would allow you get all the results you're looking for from a single operation.

Comment: Thanks for the effort Jesse. I know that DocumentDb is not an RDBMS. I would know if/when the JOIN with another object in same collection and same partition will or will not be supported.

Comment: I do not believe the Cosmos team has any immediate plans for supporting this functionality as it's not required. Either of the solutions I've given you represent the proper way of interacting with Cosmos